# Logout from Facebook on Android

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, sdk, logout

I am working on an Android Application. A part of this application is to login and logout from Facebook. Now, I am successfully able to login, but when it comes to logout there seems to be a problem. Nothing happens when I click the logout button.

My logout function is:

```
public void logoutFromFacebook() {

    mAsyncRunner.logout(this, new RequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
            Log.d("Logout from Facebook", response);
            if (Boolean.parseBoolean(response) == true) {
                // User successfully Logged out
                Intent i = new Intent(FbActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                Object state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                Object state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
        }
    });
}
```

I tried debugging it. When the code reaches the line:

```
  mAsyncRunner.logout(this, new RequestListener() {
```

I get an error. The error is:

```
Source not found. The JAR file C:\Users\...\sdk\platoforms\android-18\android.jar has no source attachment.
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: why you cant user, Session.close() ?

Comment: First of all whenever I type session, the compiler obviously asks me to import it. And when using the suggested solutions by Eclipse ADT, it imports from "android.service.textservice.SpellCheckerService"

I am highly confused

Answer (score 0):

Just access the Facebook Session in a static way and close it.

First `import com.facebook.Session`

then just call: `Session.getActiveSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();`

This will also erase the cached data, so you have to login again if you restart your application.